# Got fired because someone slipped and was injured (in public) on something I was alleged to have been carrying

Tags: termination, canada, sales

I was hired to do a simple, short term job. I was handing out flyers (aka brochure) to promote a new online store in busy public areas. The other day my manager told me there "had been an incident". The story is fragmented to me but from what I understand these are the facts

- a "male delivery driver" was holding several of our flyers
- he was frustrated with the construction work in the area and out of anger tossed the flyers on the ground
- "shortly after" this occurred, someone slipped on them and was injured and that "there were several witnesses"
- I was sent a photo of several of our flyers as some sort of proof

I had a phone call about this with my manager. Given the time and location, it must have been me or the person I was working with. I told the manager I have no idea how this could have happened and suggested wouldn't the delivery man who threw them on the ground be liable.
The next day I was terminated for this "incident" and after talking to my coworkers. I have been in touch with the partner I had been working with. It seems like she heard of this incident but said she was not terminated and had nothing to do with it. Should I ask her to tell the manager that she did not see me do something that may have caused this to happen?

We are paid for time worked, not flyers distributed. I can think of no incentive why one of us would intentionally drop them on the ground. It's offensive to me that they are acting as if I caused a stranger’s injury. The photo showed 6 flyers and I am certain I never even gave one person that many.

The company considered us contractors but it probably would be found we are employees as we don't set out schedules and don't use our own tools etc. Now, this was a short term job that I had worked a week. I was not interested in working long term for them. It would have been nice to finish the shifts I had been scheduled for. All things considered, is there any point in challenging my termination? I would feel better if I voiced my side of the story. It seems like calling my manager or a higher up one couldn't make anything worse? If I'm not interested in working for the company again, does being terminated in any other way affect me negatively? I think this may be a scam and someone just wants money from the company.

I was with my partner the whole time and would think she would be able to vouch for me. Unless of course she was plotting against me. Also I was looking at the screen shot of the complaint message again, it seemed like it was submitted using the anonymous feedback form on the website.

Comment: Where do you live? In Europe, you have some rights concerning termination, if you live in the US in an at will state, you have basically none.

Comment: @nvoigt in Canada. Since I worked there just a week, I think it's none.

Comment: Remember that you're a contractor, and typically companies don't treat contractors nearly as well as permanent staff; you're easily disposable to them. The following is speculation, but it sounds like based on the very loose, at best circumstantial 'evidence' and vague re-tellings of the events against you, maybe someone did slip on some of your company's flyers and complained to the company, and so in order to make it seem like they're taking decisive action, they threw you under the bus and said "the employee in question's contract has been terminated, please accept our apology."

Comment: Can you email the manager in question?

Comment: @Kilisi yes I can

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could let it slide.

The only thing I'd suggest is to email the manager and say it had nothing to do with you. Not for any reason of getting into a dispute or even caring (the manager already knows that), but just so there is a written record of you denying it if anything else comes of it (the whole situation is dodgy).

Example:

Dear XYX, I'm very disappointed to be terminated over the flyer incident. I had absolutely nothing to do with what happened and was unaware of the incident until I was informed and terminated.

Regards
YZY

Comment: Should I include my teammate was with me the entire time and did not see any of this?

Comment: No, just a short direct note. Don't try and open a dialogue or get anyone else involved or anything else, you're not trying to explain anything, you're just flat out denying responsibility. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: @Maximothe1 The reason you do this is so that if the company gets sued for the medical bills of the person who slipped, you're insulated from liability.

Comment: @nick012000 This is flagged as Canada, so no not medical bills.  Ongoing liability sure but not that.

Answer (score 5):

> This considered, is there any point in challenging my termination?

No.

> I would feel better if I voiced my side of the story. It seems like calling my manager or a higher up one couldn't make anything worse?

If it makes you feel better go ahead. It's not going to change anything.

> If I'm not interested in working for the company again, does being terminated in any other way affect me negatively? I think this may be a scam and someone just wants money from the company.

The main risk here is that someone will try to sue the company and they may want to pin it on you. It would not harm to talk to a lawyer and figure out what your exposure risk is. You may also consider writing a letter by certified mail that states your version of the story, clearly states that you have nothing to do with the incident and feel that you were terminated wrongly.

It's not going to change the outcome of the termination, but it's potential legal protection and might discourage them from involving you legally. Again, a lawyer can help with this.

Comment: I would personally refrain from sending the letter. There is nothing to be gained, and you can ONLY say something that may incriminate yourself. It's why lawyers tell their clients not to talk to the press, no matter how innocent their client is.