# Company that had acted suspiciously now wants my address for invoice. Should I push back or refuse?

Tags: part-time, invoices

A bit of a follow up to [Got fired because someone slipped and was injured (in public) on something I was alleged to have been carrying](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/179635/got-fired-because-someone-slipped-and-was-injured-in-public-on-something-i-was/179638?noredirect=1#comment588131_179638)

A new company I did a few days worth of work for wants me to give them my home address for an invoice. The company has acted suspiciously and the agreement was they would pay by "international email transfer" so they don't need my address. They just need my email address to pay me. Should I bother pushing back or refusing to give them my address?

Where I live it's (unfortunately) common for companies to hire contractors but in reality we are employees. This job had nothing contractor about it, regarding providing our own tools, setting our own schedule etc.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere they hired me as a contractor so they don't have to pay tax. As much information as there is about me online, I don't think my home address is public knowledge.

Comment: Well, normally an invoice does require your address mentioned. I have however done software work through a consultancy in a different country, that just needed my email id so that they could pay me via PayPal. I didn't have to give an invoice since the company generated invoices (and probably put the company address on it).

Comment: I don't know where you live, but where I live, I would consider it highly suspicious to *not* have the address of *any* business partner. Only knowing their email would be considered super shady and probably the first step to scams and tax fraud.

Comment: Why not get a PO box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make much sense to me. If you are the contractor, typically you would invoice who you did work for.

Without knowing the jurisdiction, we are unable to know exactly if they require your home address for their bookkeeping.

What is almost certainly true is they owe you money, and are legally obliged to pay you.

Given the circumstances, I would personally be inclined to push back, and demand payment for services rendered. If they have some administrative requirement to know your home address, they should have gotten it before you started your engagement with them.

It's very possible that the person who slipped has threatened to sue, and the company is trying to get all its affairs in order, making sure they have the details of anyone that was involved. If you were a contractor rather than an employee, you probably could more readily get sued yourself.

Comment: Should I just give them a fake address? They had said they didn't need at first but now are saying they do need an address.

Comment: @Maximothe1 Two weeks have passed, what has happened in that time?

Comment: They just say the accountant needs it before I get paid. Also they wont give me their address. Also I'm not really a contractor - I don't know why they would think that.

Comment: I'd just tell them that that's a problem that THEY need to sort out with their accountant.

Answer (score 1):

> so they don't need my address

No one really does these days, but it's still requested for many reasons. It's an additional identifier if nothing else.

> Should I bother pushing back or refusing to give them my address?

Without a good reason this would be unusual on your behalf and perhaps delay your payment.

Answer (score 1):

The company may or may not be acting suspiciously, that is up to you decide after you have completed your due diligence.

Firstly, as an independent contractor, although I have lived in Canada for nearly 3 years I've not come across Buyer Created Tax Invoices (BCTI) or Receiver Created Tax Invoices (RCTI). In other jurisdictions I've lived and worked, such as Australia and New Zealand, it is not unusual for companies engaging with contract labor to issue BCTI invoices to contractors. It doesn't mean they're not legal, but a cursory check of the CRA website doesn't have any information on them. Therefore it really comes down to confirming what invoice they're actually referring to.

Have you issued an invoice to the company?

If so, asking for an address in itself is not suspicious, most accounts payable systems require full contact information for a contractor/ company before payment can be made. It is not a requirement of a tax invoice in itself, these are CRA's requirements:

[image: CRA Invoice Requirements]

If you haven't sent them an invoice, at a minimum you need to ask what the invoice is and what is it for.

Additionally, confirming if you are an employee/ self-employed is more complex than being about tools and schedule. The CRA has a [document](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/publications/rc4110/employee-self-employed.html#workers_employment_status) to assist you. I don't think you'd have much luck getting a ruling of being an employee after having an agreed short term piece of work.

Comment: According to the government site you linked to, it is clear I am an employee and not a contractor. "don't think you'd have much luck getting a ruling of being an employee after having an agreed short term piece of work"  what makes you say this? No where does it say short term makes you a contractor.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think requesting an address for an invoice is a completely normal practice.